# Solving Google Code Jam 2018 Round 1C Q3

Tags: java, algorithm

I tried to solve the third problem using the Longest Increasing Sub-sequence, but failed to pass the small test set. I'm unsure if LIS is the right way to solve this problem. For an ant to join an existing stack, the total weight of the stack must be less than or equal to the weight of the ant multipled by 6.

[Link to the problem](https://codejam.withgoogle.com/2018/challenges/0000000000007765/dashboard/000000000003e0a8)

[image]
[image]

**Please see my code below. Thank you.**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int T = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

        for (int i = 1; i <= T; i++) {

            int N = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
            String[] temp = reader.readLine().split("[ ]");
            long[] weights = new long[N];
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                weights[j] = Long.parseLong(temp[j]);
            }

            int result = solution(N, weights);

            System.out.println("Case #" + i + ": " + result);
        }

        reader.close();
    }

    public static int solution(int N, long[] weights) {

        long[] total = new long[N + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < total.length; i++) {
            total[i] = -1;
        }
        total[0] = 0;

        int max = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            long current = weights[i];
            int left = 0;
            int right = max;
            int length = -1;
            while (left <= right) {
                int mid = (right - left) / 2 + left;
                if (total[mid] != -1 && total[mid] <= 6 * current) {
                    length = mid;
                    left = mid + 1;
                } else {
                    right = mid - 1;
                }
            }

            if (length != -1) {
                if (total[length + 1] == -1) {
                    total[length + 1] = total[length] + current;
                } else {
                    total[length + 1] = Math.min(total[length + 1], total[length] + current);
                }
                max = Math.max(max, length + 1);
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the problem description in your question. Links can break later and also this one requires a login.

Comment: I don't see why LIS would apply. Can't we just sort the ants by length and apply dynamic-programming based on the weights, having guaranteed that the lengths are always decreasing?

Comment: http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/59255   Some people solved it using LIS.

Comment: The official solution given by Google uses dynamic programming, so you're right.

Comment: Note that the problem says that the total weight of the stack must be less than or equal to **6x** the weight of the ant, not the weight of the ant.  This may make a difference...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: @btilly  My code has an array called "total" which tracks the total weight of the stack.  This line total[mid] <= 6 * current  checks if the total weight of the stack is less than or equal to 6 times the weight of the current ant.

Comment: @jas7 Your description in the problem was wrong.  Anyways dynamic programming is such a natural fit to this problem that I see little point in trying anything else.

Comment: @btilly I fixed the typo in the description. According to this link (codeforces.com/blog/entry/59255), some have solved this problem using LIS.

Comment: The "LIS-based" algorithm [described by marX](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/59255?#comment-428724) isn't really what I'd call LIS, since it does O(n^2) work -- I'd call it DP.  The binary search he uses is actually unnecessary (though it doesn't hurt the time complexity), since he could alternatively just make the inner loop iterate forwards from the start until the weight threshold is surpassed, saving the old value of dp[j+1] from the current iteration into a variable for the next iteration to use.

Comment: @j_random_hacker iterating forwards as you suggest would lead to inaccurate results since the lower-valued cell visited first would possibly include the new weight in its updated value, and then would be counted a second time in the update for the next (higher) cell.

Comment: @j_random_hacker  LIS can be solved in O(n^2), but there's also an O(N Log N) algorithm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence#Efficient_algorithms

Comment: @גלעדברקן: I tried to concisely explain how to overcome that specific problem: "saving the old value of dp[j+1] from the current iteration into a variable for the next iteration to use".

Comment: @jas7: AFAICS, the only time that it's helpful to describe an algorithmic technique (for solving a problem that is not actually LIS) as being "LIS" or "LIS-like" is if it uses the clever trick used in the faster O(n log n)-time algorithm for LIS to enable it to run in O(n log n) time.  marX's algorithm doesn't do that -- he's basically doing DP, with some redundant binary searches.  (If I write an O(n^2) algorithm to solve some problem and make it call binary search a few times, is this also "LIS"?)

Comment: @j_random_hacker ah, got it, my bad, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The term, LIS, may be used inaccurately in that blog post. Clearly, we want the longest sequence, but what property would be increasing?

Given a sequence of increasing ant lengths, we are looking downward towards the start of the pile; and we can say that, generally, given a new weight, `w`, any sequence of length `l`, stored in `ls`, with weight `ls[l]`, can be updated to the smaller of its current weight or `ls[l - 1] + w`.

(Based on [markX's reference](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/59255) to his [answer](https://github.com/mfornet/acm-icpc-solutions/blob/master/codejam/2018-round1c/c/sol.cpp).)

Comment: For each ant, I use binary search to look for the longest stack that this ant can join (in other words, a stack whose total weight is <= 6* this ant's weight).

Comment: total[i]=x,  This means that a stack of length i has a total weight of x. total[i]=-1 if there does not exist a stack of length equal to i.

Comment: I update the value of total[i] to be as small as possible.  total[length + 1] = Math.min(total[length + 1], total[length] + current);

Comment: @jas7 right, but you need to do this for all relevant `i`s, not just one.